# Windows 10 - hangs on a black screen for 40s before the login screen shows up

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, ssd

I've been facing for a few months now the following issue: my laptop takes about 1 minute to get to my Desktop (or to restart). I've got a decent SSD - a year ago I bought the laptop and the drive and installed Windows 10 on it. Back then, it took around 15s to start from cold boot. After one day (I don't clearly remember what happened), after showing my OEM's logo (Fujitsu) and the white rotating loading dots, it got to a pitch black screen, no cursor visible - the only lit up thing are the lights on the case. After 30 to 40s, the login screen appears. Restart is also affected. I've also tried booting into safe mode with minimal settings, into diagnostic startup as well, it still takes somewhere around 40s for the black screen to disappear. I've got plenty of disk space, 16 gigs of RAM and after the login screen appears everything works as blazing fast as before - it's just that wait at that black screen between the initial loading and the login screen. I used to have that issue on my old laptop that had an HDD (and it's probably normal for an older HDD), but there's no way it is normal for this SSD that's less than a year old and works perfectly fine everywhere else. I've also run DISM and sfc /scannow, updated to version 2004 (I was on 1910), it is all still the same. Fast startup and hibernation are disabled. Any ideas for troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A black screen with rotating dots for 30 seconds to a minute on an SSD drive is fairly normal. That can be 2 or 3 minutes on a hard drive.

> I've got plenty of disk space, 16 gigs of RAM and after the login
> screen appears everything works as blazing fast as before -

So your system is normal so far as I can see.

Update BIOS, Chipset, Video and all other drivers.

Restart and update Windows 10 including Optional Windows 10 cumulative and .NET updates (appeared in V2004)

Total boot time for an SSD on a fast, good system to smooth operation is about 2 minutes.

Total boot time for a HDD on a decent, good system to smooth operation is about 6 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but there are no further updates pending. All drivers and everything pretty much is up-to-date. The screen, however, has NO rotating dots (I thought I made that clear originally). The OEM's logo disappears, the dots disappear. Just a pitch black screen before login, for 40 seconds - nothing happening, not even the mouse is visible, no dots, not even backlight.

Wondering how previously I was at my Desktop for 15s (and that was until August), now it takes a minute - and the SSD reports show that the SSD hasn't really degraded.

Comment: Dots can work either way (rotating white dots or black screen for a halt minute on an SSD and I see this frequently so if everything is up to date then I still say normal.

Comment: Fair enough then, I guess.

Comment: I've recently got this problem too. Did you ever find a solution? The screen just goes black for a fair while before the login screen eventually appears. Pretty sure an update caused it.